# Keep Collapsable Div Open After Postback

Tags: javascript, html, css, postback

I have a panel containing a bunch of these filters. By default they are all collapsed, but when you click the button it expands the div. However, every time there is a postback the div is collapsed. How can I make the current state of the div persist across postbacks?

```
                <h4 class="contentFilterHeader">Start Date</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#startDate">
                <div id="startDate" class="collapse">
                    <label for="from">Before:</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="date">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startPicker" runat="server" name="date" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `runat=server` to the entire `#startDate` div and set Class to them from code behind after checking `isPostBack` or better yet append a little javascript code to open it on page ready

```
startDate.innerHtml = startDate.innerHtml + "<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $('#startDate').collapse('show') }) </script>";
```

Assuming you are using c# and [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

EDIT

You can use the following code
http://codepen.io/jammer99/pen/eZyqEN

```
var t,
  //read cookie and determine if any panel was open before
  earlierPanel = readCookie("openpanel")
  //if value is found collapse all earlier panels and then open the last panel
if (earlierPanel) {
  $('#accordion .panel-collapse').removeClass("in");
  $("#" + earlierPanel).addClass("in")
}
//reset the behaviour when user opens another panel
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(w) {
  t = w.target;
  createCookie("openpanel", $(t).attr("id"))
})

// remove cookie value using the following or you can write your code to delete the cookie
$('#accordion').on('hide.bs.collapse', function(w) {  
  createCookie("openpanel","")
})

function createCookie(name, value) {
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var e = name + "=";
  var a = document.cookie.split(";");
  for (var d = 0; d < a.length; d++) {
    var f = a[d];
    while (f.charAt(0) == " ") {
      f = f.substring(1, f.length)
    }
    if (f.indexOf(e) == 0) {
      return f.substring(e.length, f.length)
    }
  }
  return null
};
```

Comment: I am using c# and bootstrap. However, I want the divs to be collapsed by default. If the user opens one then I want it to stay open across postbacks until they close it

Comment: correct. Thats what this tiny javascript snippet will do. it will detect postbacks and open the div on postback. you just need to specify the correct target which you can do by using a cookie perhaps.

Comment: Maybe I have a misunderstanding but that code would go in the Page Load event of the codebehind and collapse the div every time there's a postback? I don't necessarily want to the div to be open. I only want it open if it was opened by the user right before the postback occurred. Otherwise it should be closed by default, which is already the case.

Comment: @JohnSmith Can you try my modified code. This code is javascript only and requires no server side coding. :) 
p.s. I know its a bit overkill but it should do the job.

Comment: The only problem is, once I open it once it stays open across postbacks even after I close it

Comment: @JohnSmith check edited code. added a fix for that. now if you close all the divs it will fall back to whatever was the initial value for the divs

Comment: Now is there any way to modify this so that all panels that were opened remain open rather than just the last one to be opened?

Answer (score 1):

Use a HiddenField to store the state of the panel.